# MySQL pagination

Tags: performance, innodb, optimization, mysql-5.7, pagination

MySQL - I am trying to fix this pagination issue on my servers . The RAM is 40 GB and the innodb_buffer_pool_size is set to 36 GB which is a little more than 80%. Still getting paging alerts. Any advise?

Comment: can you expnad on the problem with the oagination. 36 gig semm a bit accesive

Comment: Let's see a "paging alert".  If it is related to "swappng", lower the buffer_pool_size as needed.  (Swapping is much worse on performance than having a smaller buffer_pool.)

Comment: This is an extract from the alert : 
<server_xyz> -(DATABASE - MYSQL) Paging Space is 89% used <server_xyz>

This may not help a lot but I have done a lot of research on this and havent found much but to have the queries to use LIMIT and OFFSET clause. I dont have much control on what is being queried on from the front end but I am sure these are already in place.